# Keyboard output does not matches

Tags: keyboard

Keyboard output does not match.
For example, clicking  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  gives `"` instead of `@`
Another example, if I click `|` key the result is `~`; if I click `?` the result is `-`.

Keyboard and wireless mouse dell 117 and dell optiplex 780 working with windows 10 PT-PT language. How can I get the file where windows stores keyboard key codes and change the commands?

Comment: Do you have a US keyboard? If so choose a US keyboard layout.

Comment: A picture of your keyboard would help us identify its native nationality.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to switch to Brasilian Portuguese, that swaps the @ and " keys, amongst others - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout EU Portuguese uses the UK English type of ISO layout, which is different to the US ANSI. Brasilian switches some of those back towards ANSI.

EU Portuguese
[image]

Brasilian Portuguese
[image]